# Drupal: Multiple Node Creation

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-nodes

I've found myself in a situation where I need to have one node that allows for only ONE image to be associated with it. In other words, the maximum images that be can be attached to my image type "IMAGE", is 1. My problem is, that users must be able to upload several images at once. So, I need one of the following:

- A way to create several nodes one after the other (maybe flexi node?? but the problem with flexi node is that I need to have prepopulated node refence field that can't be updated when I add another flexi node field)
- A way to upload, and inser the data myself (creating distinct nodes) (i.e. create a custom upload interface)

I would of course prefer the first option, but other than FlexiNode, what is the best thing to use?

Comment: Flexi Node is definitely not an option due to the prepopulation issue I have.

Comment: What data other than the image do you need in the nodes?

Answer (score 1):

CCK imagefields add images to exsisting nodes but by default has many images. You may want to look at [the image module](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/image) which creates an image node type, or [node images](http://drupal.org/project/node_images) which seems to associate an image with a node (it supports bulk uploading).

Answer (score 0):

You have looked at the [Content Construction Kit](http://drupal.org/project/cck) and its built-in image field, have you? I believe flexinode is pretty outdated.

Comment: Yes, but your missing the core issue of my problem. I need to create a page where the user can create SEVERAL instances of ONE node. I.e. Access this page and then create several images so that i have one db entry per image.